# Access property of function execution (like doSomething().cool)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

How should the code be written so the test could access the property of function execution here:

`_instance.addProducts(_product).products`

**Test**

```
describe(`ONE product added`, () => {
  const _product = {
    name: 'product1',
    price: 1.50,
    quantity: 1
  };
  let _instance
  let _cart

  beforeEach(() => {
    _instance = window[MODULE_NAME]();
    _cart = _instance.addProducts(_product);
  });

  test(`cart's products`, () => {
    expect(_cart.products).toEqual([_product]);
  });
})
```

**Code**

```
(function() {
  var MODULE_NAME = 'shoppingcartModel',
      _Cart = {
        products: [],
        total: {
          beforeVAT: 0,
          afterVAT: 0,
          VAT: 0
        }
      };

  window[MODULE_NAME] = function() {

    return {

      addProducts: function(newOrExistingProducts) {
        return _Cart.products.push(newOrExistingProducts);
      }

    };
  };
})()
```

The test is written perfectly and can't be modified. What kind of wizardry is that? :)

I did try to refactor `addProducts` to the variable and append `products` property on it, but it's not the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return `_Cart` from your `addProducts` method and get products property from the returned `_Cart` object

```
addProducts: function(newOrExistingProducts) {
    _Cart.products.push(newOrExistingProducts);
    return _Cart;
}
```

When you write `_instance.addProducts(_product).products` you are not trying to get products from `_instance.addProducts` but from it's return value.

To get the products from `_instance.addProducts` you should write `_instance.addProducts.products` instead